# does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method

Tags: c#

I get the error message written in the title for my variables.

```
using webFRIEDneu._Grab;

namespace webFRIED._Grab
{

    public partial class Grabserie1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public string GetIdent(int Zahl, string Typ)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;

            if (Typ == "Römisch")
                s = ArabicToRoman.Convert(Zahl);

            if (Typ == "Arabisch")
                s = Zahl.ToString();

            return s;
        }//Kovertierung in Arabisch/Römisch/Alphabet

        public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }//Page_Load

        public void btn_Speichern_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            int Ident1Von, Ident1Bis, Ident2Von, Ident2Bis, Ident3Von, Ident3Bis;
            string Trennzeichen;

            Ident1Von = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident1_von.Text.ToString());
            Ident1Bis = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident1_bis.Text.ToString());
            Ident2Von = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident2_von.Text);
            Ident2Bis = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident2_bis.Text);
            Ident3Von = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident3_von.Text);
            Ident3Bis = int.Parse(this.tb_Grabident3_bis.Text);
            Trennzeichen = this.tb_Trennzeichen.Text;

            for (int i1von = Ident1Von; i1von <= Ident1Bis; i1von++)
            {
                for (int i2von = Ident2Von; i2von <= Ident2Bis; i2von++)
                {
                    for (int i3von = Ident3Von; i3von <= Ident3Bis; i3von++)
                    {
                        //lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {1} {3}", GetIdent(i1von, this.ddl_Grabident1.Text), Trennzeichen, GetIdent(i2von, this.ddl_Grabident2.Text), GetIdent(i3von, this.ddl_Grabident3.Text)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }//btn_Speichern


        protected void btn_Hilfe_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }//btn_Help


        protected void btn_Beenden_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }//btn_Beenden


        /********************************************************************************
        *                                                                               *
        *                  Private Methoden                                             *
        *                                                                               *
        ********************************************************************************/


}
}
```

I get the error message already said. Marked with a yellow triangle are all my int variables.

I don't know why its telling me there is no definition for the method...

What did I do wrong? Is there any advice? Maybe there is a missing using directive?

Comment: Add the actual error message and the stacktrace in the post

Comment: And why do you have `ToString()` for `Ident1Von` and `Ident1Bis` but not for the others?